# Run a query automatically SSMS without SQL server agent

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures, sql-server-agent

I'm a new PowerBI developer.
I am inserting data from the Azure SQL database via SSMS.
I don't have access to a server agent for being able to create jobs.
I just want to run 4-5 queries (1 query = 1 step for my job). Is there a simple way to do this automatically for example?

Comment: for example, if i can run a .sql file with all my query-code inside automatically; where can i save that file etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's no server agent in Azure SQL DB, so you cannot create jobs as you do in on-prem or on Azure VM installations.

However, you do have Elastic jobs on Azure which can run queries on Azure SQL Database periodically.

See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-overview).